# Table Design converting excel to access

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a system in Excel that is becoming to complex to manage within excel.  Basically, we have 3 tables:

customers (CustID,Name)
Services (SvcID, Service Code, Description)
Transactions (TransID, Date, CustID, SvcID)

A customer can have up to 15 services in one day, but they will never have the same service in the same day.

In Access, I know that I can use a query to filter the tables to give me the services for each customer for each day, but each service will show up on a separate line.

HERE'S THE KICKER - The user wants to see all of the services rendered for one day on one line regardless of whether there was 1 service rendered or if there were 15.

In excel, I had 16 columns (customer, svc1, svc2, svc3, etc) where each svc column would hold one service.  I then created another worksheet that concatenated the service columns into a single column.  The problem with this approach is that I was saving them one day at a time (I have a template that automatically saves the file with todays date when it is opened).  While not good for data mining, it did seem to idiot proof some of the data entry.

So, basically, I'm asking for suggestions on how to improve my table design so that I can create a report for each day that will show each customer on one line with all of their services right next to it in one field or text box.  Should I stick with the original svc1, svc2, svc3 design?  If so, how do I set up relationships between these services and the services table to maintain referential integrity?

Comment: If data structure is properly normalized, don't redesign just to accommodate a special requirement. Review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Answer (score 0):

If you start out with a normalized design, there are two techniques you can use to produce a spreadsheet style view, with up to 15 services on one line.

One is crosstabulation and the other is a pivot table report.  I've had good results with the pivot table report.  This uses excel to actually produce the spread sheet view.

So why normalize, if you are just going to denormalize  when you create the view? For the sake of the other things you are going to do wth the same data.  I don't know what those other things are, but you probably do.

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to quickly pull up one customer and see all dates where they had services and the services that they had.  With my current excel design, I can use file explorer to find the dates that a customer had services (since each day is saved as a separate excel file), but then I have to open each file to see what services they had.  If I convert to Access, I can quickly do this.  I can also quickly count the number of dates of services, etc..